# Safari navigating into appium port instead of website?

Tags: c#, ios, selenium, safari, appium

[image]

output of the below script.In address bar its passing appium port instead of passing google.

```
 [OneTimeSetUp]
  public void BeforeEachTest()
   {

   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "iPhone Simulator");
    capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "11.1");
    capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "Safari");
    capabilities.SetCapability("bundleId", "com.apple.mobilesafari");
    capabilities.SetCapability("showXcodeLog", true);
    driver = new IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110));
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = IMPLICIT_TIMEOUT_SEC;

}

[Test]
public void AppLaunches()
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

}
[OneTimeTearDown]
public void tearDown(){
    driver.Quit();
}
```

i'm new to automation

Comment: Anybody plz answer ...i'm new to automation

Answer (score 0):

Try to limit your capabilities to required ones only:

```
capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "iOS");
capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "Safari");
capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "11.1");
capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "iPhone Simulator");
```

plus another one (Sim-only [capability](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md)):

```
capabilities.SetCapability("safariInitialUrl", "http://www.google.com");
```

And then try to create a session and see how it goes.

Comment: I already tried with this...but i need to use driver for further process, for that case its not capable. I'm having problem with driver initialization ...can you please give me a solution . For details - Xcode 9.1,Appium 1.7.1,iOS 11.1 and simulator - iPhone 6

Comment: You do need to initialise driver as you did previously. Just try to do it with capabilities I put in answer. Then, put appium server log in case of failure. It's hard to fully got your issue without those logs

Answer (score 0):

instead of driver.navigate.GoToUrl, we can use driver.navigate.to OR driver.get

Comment: problem with driver initialization, bcz after the driver initialization it's not executing any code. I tried to put the log file on the stack but its show me an error.

Comment: can you use 'url' instead of 'uri' in driver def